# Get all records matchung some conditions OR at least 10 by adding some others

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to get *all* records matching these conditions:

- (`userid = 1 AND (status < 2 OR time > INTERVAL '1 day')`)

And if there are less than 10 records and more (if available) for:

- `userid = 1`

Get up to 10 (last, by `time`)?

Comment: Please always provide your Postgres version and a table definition including constraints (most importantly `NOT NULL` constraints). Details of the query often depend on details of the table. Do you really have an `interval` column named "time"? Would be unfortunate on two accounts.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Are you limiting all results to 10 rows or do you want *all* matching rows and the limit only to apply when you borrow additional matches.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I thought that we are talking about last version by default ;<

Comment: A large percentage of people asking questions here do *not* run the latest version. It's all too often that (after much discussion and time wasted) it turns out that a particular solution does not work for an outdated version. *Always* mention version numbers of software in question in any case. The default is to assume the current version, but that's a workaround, not a good solution. And remember that this is a public forum, question and answer will be around for longer. Software versions are useful documentation beyond your immediate use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to `get all records matching`. A hard `LIMIT 10` would be wrong for the purpose. You only want to add rows up to a maximum of 10 according to *secondary* conditions ***if*** there are not enough rows for your *primary* conditions. But there can be more than 10 rows already for the primary condition alone.

#### PL/pgSQL solution

The *fastest* way I can think of is a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tbl_top(_uid int = 1, _min int = 10)
  RETURNS SETOF tbl AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ct int;
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  userid = _uid
AND   (status < 2 OR time > interval '1 day')
ORDER  BY time DESC;

GET DIAGNOSTICS _ct = ROW_COUNT;
_ct := _min - _ct;  -- calculate diff

IF _ct > 0 THEN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT *
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  userid = _uid
   AND   (status < 2 OR time > interval '1 day') IS NOT TRUE
   ORDER  BY time DESC
   LIMIT  _ct;
END IF;

END 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_tbl_top();
```

I added two parameters: for `user_id` (_uid) and for the minimum row count (`_min`). They default to `1` / `10` respectively. So you get at least 10 rows if there are enough for `userid = 1` when you call the function without providing parameters. Or, to do the same for user 7 and a minimum of 9 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM f_tbl_top(7, 9);
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM f_tbl_top(_uid := 7, _min := 9);
```

Also careful if your column `time` can be NULL. Then you need:

```
ORDER  BY time DESC NULLS LAST
```

But don't use a basic type name like `time` as column name to begin with, even less for an `interval`, which is rather misleading.

The condition for the second `SELECT` might be optimized depending on your actual table definition.

#### Pure SQL

If you prefer a pure SQL solution, you could use a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  userid = 1
   AND   (status < 2 OR time > interval '1 day')
   ORDER  BY time DESC
   )
TABLE cte
UNION ALL
( -- parentheses required!
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  userid = 1
AND   (status < 2 OR time > interval '1 day') IS NOT TRUE
ORDER  BY time DESC
LIMIT  GREATEST((SELECT 10 - count(*) FROM cte), 0)
);
```

The [`GREATEST(...)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) expression in the 2nd `LIMIT` avoids an illegal negative number in the `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: That LIMIT in CTE is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks you so much! Pure SQL variant working perfectly.

Comment: @ShamilYakupov: Nice. Performance might be improved further, depending on actual table definition and available indexes.

Comment: Real query looks much bigger than one in your answer (1128 chars). Is it normal size for query?

Comment: @ShamilYakupov: If top performance is critical, consider the plpgsql function, which should be a bit faster. More might be possible, depending on table definition / indexes. *If* you need that, ask a *new question* where you provide the necessary information as instructed here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by prioritization using `order by`.  If you want 10 records:

```
select t.*
from table t
where userid = 1
order by (case when status < 2  OR time > INTERVAL '1 day' then 1 else 2 end),
         time desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: If I read the question right, this is wrong. There can be more than 10 resulting rows.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Second condition say `get more up to 10`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: *Primary* instruction says `get all records matching some conditions`. *Secondary* instruction says:  `if there is less than 10  ... get more up to 10`. Seems clear to me.

Comment: I read it as getting a maximum of 10.  To me, there is no other way to read the second bullet point -- although the title clearly gives another meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the last 10 no matter what date.

But still that can bring you less than 10.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM your table
  WHERE userid = 1 AND status < 2
  order by time desc
  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I wanted all records matching first condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM table
  WHERE (userid = 1 AND (status < 2 OR time > INTERVAL '1 day'))
  ORDER BY time
  LIMIT 10) a
  UNION SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM table
  WHERE userid = 1
  ORDER BY time
  LIMIT 10) b
  LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: There is no strict LIMIT 10 for first condition.